# What is it called when I got enough sleep?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

Do we just say, I’ve had enough sleep, or I’m full of sleep or something else?

Answer (score 39):

You could say "I am [well-rested](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/well-rested)".

If you want to refer to last night, you could also say "I had a good night's sleep" to indicate the amount of sleep you got was sufficient to plentyful.

Comment: "well-rested" is the standard term in official reports such as air accident investigations.  "The pilots were on their first sector of the day and were well rested..."

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that you can use just “rested,” and the “well” will be implied.

Answer (score 12):

You can simply say that you had  ***[a good (night's) sleep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20good%20night%27s%20sleep)***:

> - a night in which one sleeps well.
> - *Did you have a good night's sleep? I need a good night's sleep to be at my best in the morning.*

(M-W)

Comment: A ["**good night's rest**"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/general/sixminute/2009/03/090324_6min_sleep_page.shtml) also works. Pity you didn't mention that also.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, apparently less common, though. Probably for this reason it is not present in dictionaries as idiomatic: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+good+night%E2%80%99s+sleep%2C+a+good+night%E2%80%99s++rest&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20good%20night%20%27s%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20good%20night%20%27s%20rest%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This answer seems to imply "I had a good sleep" is valid (with the parentheses). While that's grammatical, it sounds funny in AmE, and I've never heard it outside of people trying to be funny. Is it a regional thing?

Answer (score -1):

One more way to say *enough sleep* is **salubrious** sleep. Salubrious sleep is healthy sleep. You feel you had an enough sleep. It gives you a feeling of contentment.

**Salubrious** [Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/salubrious)

> Health-giving; healthy.

*Citation from the books*:

[Healthy Living in Late Renaissance Italy](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Jst7AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA144&dq=%22salubrious%20sleep%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtuvOB2ZTdAhVLsY8KHdpMBYAQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22salubrious%20sleep%22&f=false) By Sandra Cavallo, Tessa Storey

> They made for more **salubrious sleep** according to the principles of healthy life promoted in the advice literature...

[The Critical Review: Or, Annals of Literature, Volume 21 edited](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=dcMPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA76&dq=%22salubrious%20sleep%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtuvOB2ZTdAhVLsY8KHdpMBYAQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22salubrious%20sleep%22&f=false) by Tobias George Smollett

> We, indeed, consider dreaming to be only an interruption of **salubrious sleep**.

Comment: Never (as a native British English speaker in my 30s) have I ever heard the phrase "salubrious sleep".

Comment: Possibly it's a medical term. Possibly it's more common in American English. I don't know. I can only speak from my own experience.

Comment: Also a native british english speaker (late 20s), particularly well read, I know the word Salubrious and I've never seen it used in this context either. That said, the quotes seem good, and depending on whether the OP is looking for Purple Prose this might be a good option!

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 there is a reason, I substantiated my answer with excerpts from two books.

Comment: @ubihatt While I've not downvoted, my finger did rather hover over that arrow for a moment or two. I don't doubt that the quotes are legitimate, but the phrasing of the question strongly suggests to me that OP wants to know how English speakers typically express this. The multiple native speakers claiming to have never encountered the phrase before (you can add me to the list) says "salubrious sleep" is very much not that.

Comment: @ChrisH hence my own recommendation that it'd be good for use as "purple prose", but that it's definitely not common usage. In fact, after my own google-search for the phrase itself, I found the two quotes above, this very stack-exchange question and a bunch of partial matches. So it's certainly not common!

Comment: Google Books shows zero results for "salubrious sleep" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=salubrious+sleep&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url= - you may just add that it is not a common expression, but one worth mentioning.

Comment: @user070221 results from [google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=salubrious+sleep) and [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22salubrious+sleep%22&ie=&oe=)

Comment: @ubihatt - yes, it looks a more literary, technical expression.

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question.   I can say that I’m well rested or that I got a good night’s sleep last night. But how do I say that using *salubrious*?  “I’ve had the requisite amount of salubrious sleep!?!”  From what I can see salubrious doesn’t include the idea of ‘*enough*’.  Even the examples given here indicate that salubrious sleep can be interrupted. so while I might have been on my way to a good night’s sleep, my dog’s barking in the middle of the night put a stop to that.

Comment: @Jim Perhaps the idea is that it's well known that it's unhealthy to get too little sleep. So insufficient sleep cannot also be salubrious. BTW, I'm an American in my 50's and I don't think I've ever heard the term before, either. Both citations seem to be from technical writing.

Comment: I don't get all the hate for this answer. It's clearly used, and it's obvious from the word "salubrious" that it would not be used in common speech. And it's at least reasonably ambiguous whether OP only wanted phrases suitable for everyday use (although I suppose you wouldn't use "salubrious speech" in the first person — it's still relevant to the question). Also, "salubrious" is an incredible word and deserves to be used more often. [Also here's another book using it](https://bit.ly/2PSbrc2). Could, I suppose, edit to mention that it wouldn't be used outside of a technical context.

Comment: @shim the main issue I have with it is that it doesn’t answer the question- “I am salubrious” doesn’t mean “I am well rested”. “I had salubrious sleep” doesn’t even mean “I had plenty of sleep”. It’s a great word, but it doesn’t fit here.

Comment: Yea, I guess "salubrious sleep" is referring to the quality of the sleep, not the quantity, which is what the question is focused on.